# Can a forensic exam find an image's geographic metadata after geotagging was disabled?

Tags: privacy, forensics, geolocation

We recently did a lab in my computer forensics class where we analyzed images of a suspect's phone, and used the metadata of the photos found therein to show he was in the vicinity of where a crime had occurred. This was handed to us on a silver platter, because the latitude and longitude coordinates were found in the photos' "Properties." Pretty cool stuff.

However, clever criminals are more careful about covering their tracks and forensic scientists won't have the luxury of being given such metadata. Because "Location Services" can be disabled on phones and cameras, *is it possible to forensically excavate latitude and longitude coordinates given a photo and/or forensic image from a device where "Location Services" was deactivated and, if so, what is at least one method that can be used to get this information?*

---

**Update:** Thanks to John Deters for explaining the ways in which a forensic scientist might pinpoint a photo's geolocation from an image where geographic metadata collection was deactivated.

*What if the forensic scientist is just given a photo (not an image) with no metadata? Is it forensically possible to chart where that photo was taken, provided that there's no revealing information in the picture; e.g., street signs, unique buildings, etc.?*

Comment: Is only a photo provided or an image of the phone?

Comment: Can we look at both scenarios?

Comment: Sure, but you should specify that in your question. ;)

Comment: Depends on if you are limited to digital forensics. If you aren't, then there are a bunch of ways to locate someone based on the picture, such as forensic botany.

Comment: I updated my question to include a photo *and* a forensic image @TomK.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to limit this to digital forensics, @forest.

Comment: While [some thieves are stupid when it comes to phones](https://www.cultofmac.com/329373/numbskull-thief-takes-identifying-selfie-while-robbing-an-iphone/) I would expect most that are clever enough to turn off Location Services will also refrain from taking photos near their scene of crime.

Comment: @TripeHound You greatly overestimate the intelligence of the average criminal.

Comment: Re. your italicized question, do you count analysis of slight imperfections in the lens? Those are often retained in a pure bitmap copy of the photo and can uniquely identify the hardware used to take it. A search warrant can permit analysis of the device to later determine where exactly the photo was taken.

Comment: Sure @forest. I never even considered something like that. I'm open to ideas; anything that'll allow me to view the problem differently, preventing me from throwing in the towel too early when hunting for evidence. So these "slight imperfections" can uniquely identify a device in the same way a serial number or assortment of stickers can?

Comment: Sort of. If you, for example, post a mundane image to Instagram with a given camera, and then take another picture of something you don't want to be tied to you (whistleblowing or other dangerous journalism, for example), the two images can be matched up. Alone, the imperfections do not identify your particular device unless they are known before it is sold to you. If you have ever publicly and non-anonymously posted an image with that camera, then this issue applies to any other photos you may take that you don't want attributed to you.

Comment: I just saw a great visual explanation on HNQ: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60114/what-am-i-photographing-inside-my-camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to correlate the photo’s time with other artifacts recovered from the device. Those other artifacts might provide evidence of location.

Consider network logs. If the phone was connected to a free WiFi access point at a restaurant two minutes before the photo was taken, and remained connected afterwards, the photo was probably taken within a few dozen meters of the restaurant.

Check the browser history. Some sites ask for location data; if they were connected to a site that had permission, it could still be present.

Check for other apps that use location data, such as IFTTT or a home automation app. They may have a ‘geofence’ feature and it may keep a log of where the device has been. Or they may have a navigation app that tracked where they were.

Were other photos taken near the same time? If they have their EXIF data still intact, you can show that the phone couldn’t have gotten very far between pictures.

Also consider what’s in the picture. The background can easily give away the location. See [this article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/03/us-spy-lab-hopes-to-geotag-every-outdoor-photo-on-social-media/) for info about such efforts on a large scale.

Cell records can also place the phone in a geographic area, but the phone may not store that detail, and you’ll need a warrant to get the records from the wireless carrier.

If you find one bit of evidence, don’t stop looking. You will need more than one data point to convince people.

Comment: Given a similar [thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104986/can-a-random-person-find-me-if-my-location-services-are-turned-off) on locating people via phone despite Location Services being turned off, it seems reasonable to say that if you connect to a network, then that gets logged and you can be placed. Where are network logs housed and can clients access them?

Perhaps this is suited for another discussion, but I wonder if it's possible for a client to block the locating capabilities of the phone company while still preserving (most of) the phone's functionality.

Comment: Apple’s iOS location services used to keep all of its data in a TinySQL database file. I plotted a KML of the data from my phone once , and it drew a picture of cell towers along my most recent vacation route, and a well-travelled swath to my workplace. But I don’t know where that’s all kept now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question:

> *What if the forensic scientist is just given a photo (not an image) with no metadata? Is it forensically possible to chart where that
>   photo was taken, provided that there's no revealing information in the
>   picture; e.g., street signs, unique buildings, etc.?*

The answer is "probably not, and definitely not with any certainty or precision".

There may be some clues in the photo, though, such as shadows cast by objects of known size.  If the time and date the photograph was taken is available, and if the height of the object casting the shadow is known, and if the length of the shadow can be measured from the photo, the angle of the sun can be computed to reveal the approximate latitude the photo was taken at.  ([To learn more about the concept you can look at an online shadow length calculator here.](http://planetcalc.com/1875/))

While this won't prove that a picture was taken at a particular place, it might help prove that it was *not* taken somewhere.  For example, consider someone investigating a crime in New York.  If the person who took the photo said they were in Hawaii at the time, and the photo shows a shadow consistent with a latitude of 19 degrees, that picture won't prove they were in Hawaii but it could help their claim that they weren't in New York.

Comment: If you want to experiment with this, use a publicly available satellite photo of a skyscraper ( I used Google Maps. It helps to pick a flat city. ) Measure the length of the shadow using the map legend. The image should also have a timestamp available.  Look up the height of the building in Wikipedia. Reversing the equation will yield the latitude. Check your work against the map’s reported location.